# CA2100 security warning in Excel OleDb select query

Tags: c#, excel, code-analysis, oledbcommand

We have a code block that reads the contents of the first sheet in an Excel file to a DataTable. We know that the data in the first sheet is in tabular form, so no problem there.

Our development environment: VS 12, C#.

Relevant line of code is as follows:

```
OleDbCommand objCmdSelect =
    new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]", objConn);
```

where the variable sheetName is the name of the first sheet. objConn is the connection object.

However, that line gives a CA2100 "Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities" warning in Code Analysis, due to our string concatenation. AFAIK, table names cannot be parameterized. Solutions I came up with:

1) Switch to Microsoft's Excel library. But this is slower (is it?).

2) Suppress the warning. Don't want it actually.

Is there a better solution, or a best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Can `sheetName` be entered by a potentially malicious user?  If not, then just suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that sheetName is actually the name of a sheet, and either it is properly escaped or it doesn't contain special characters. Then just suppress the warning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know this is not a security threat. I just wanted to find a way to overcome CA2100 without suppressing.